# Pandas.eval replacement in polars

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-polars

Suppose I have an expression like "col3 = col2 + col1" so pandas we can directly call pandas.dataframe.eval() but in polars i cannot find such method.

I have series.eval in polars but no luck as i want evaluate user given expression on a dataframe.

Comment: There is the [SQL context](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.sql_expr.html#polars.sql_expr) but you'd need to alter the assignment part e.g. `df.with_columns(pl.sql_expr("col1 + col2 as col3"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Acception strings

You can pass `SQL` to `pl.sql_expr`.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "col1": [1, 2],
    "col2": [1, 2],
})
df.select(
    pl.sql_expr("col2 + col1 as col3")
)
```

Or you can run a complete SQL query:

```py
ctxt = pl.SQLContext(
    frames = {"df": df}
)
ctxt.execute("""
    SELECT col2 + col1 as col3 FROM df
    """,
    eager=True
)
```

### Accept expressions directly

> i want evaluate user given expression on a dataframe.

I would accept `pl.Expression` directly instead of strings. This gives more type safety than strings and probably also a better user experience as you can have autocomplete and the IDE may show available methods/arguments.

Comment: I have an expression like '( ind128715 * ind128717/12 ) / ( 1 - (1+ ind128717/12) ** - dim23358___prop37803 )' but sql_expr giving an error 'Expected an expression : found *'

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that gets closer to what `pandas.eval` provides. Likely more needs to be added to `eval_globals`, this is a minimal working example:

```py
import polars as pl

eval_globals = {
    expr: getattr(pl.Expr, expr) for expr in dir(pl.Expr) if not expr.startswith("_")
}
# Add any functions that create expressions that don't live in pl.Expr
eval_globals["col"] = pl.col


def parse_expr(s: str, eval_locals: dict[str, pl.Expr]) -> pl.Expr:
    """Parse a string to a polars expression.

    `locals` should be a map of each column name in the dataframe to a pl.Expr
    for pl.col(column name).

    """
    return eval(s, eval_globals, eval_locals)


def test_eval():
    df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [2, 3, 4]})
    eval_locals = {col: pl.col(col) for col in df.columns}
    s = "(a * b + 1).alias('ab++')"
    expected = (pl.col("a") * pl.col("b") + 1).alias("ab++")
    actual = parse_expr(s, eval_locals)
    assert df.select(actual).equals(df.select(expected))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you're doing in pandas:

```py
(pd.DataFrame({'col1': 1, 'col2': [4, 2, 18]})
 .eval('col3 = col1 + col2')
)

   col1  col2  col3
0     1     4     5
1     1     2     3
2     1    18    19
```

And this would be how I would do it in polars:

```py
(pl.DataFrame({'col1':1, 'col2':[4, 2, 18]})
 .with_columns(col3 = pl.col('col1') + pl.col('col2'))
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i32  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 4    ┆ 5    │
│ 1    ┆ 2    ┆ 3    │
│ 1    ┆ 18   ┆ 19   │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘
```