# polars build filter query from kwargs

Tags: python-polars

I can't figure out how to build a simple polars filter command dynamically from kwargs.

With panda's it seems quite straight forward:

```
df.query(" and ".join(f"{key} == {repr(value)}" for key, value in kwargs.items()))
```

Comment: Perhaps you can show an actual example input/output, it looks like maybe you're trying to do something like: `df.filter(pl.all_horizontal(pl.col(key) == pl.lit(value) for key, value in kwargs.items()))
` or perhaps `pl.SQLContext`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76762637

Comment: @jqurious awesome, exactly what I needed. Please make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Update]:** [kwargs support has been added to `.filter()`](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/11740) which will be available from Polars `0.19.9`

This means the `.all_horizontal()` example below can be simplified to:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 2, 1], "B": [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]})

kwargs = {"A": 2, "B": 5}

df.filter(**kwargs)
```

```py
shape: (1, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 2   ┆ 5   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

---

Polars expressions are actually objects and can be described as *"lazy"*.

```py
>>> pl.col('foo') == pl.lit('bar')
<polars.expr.expr.Expr at 0x1273a0880>
```

```py
>>> pl.when(pl.col('foo').is_in([1, 2, 3]))
<polars.expr.whenthen.When at 0x12a37f6a0>
```

They don't actually do anything until they are evaluated by Polars itself, e.g. inside `df.with_columns()`

This means you can just build your expression directly:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 2, 1], "B": [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]})

kwargs = {"A": 2, "B": 5}

df.with_columns(query = 
   pl.concat_list(
      pl.col(key) == pl.lit(value) for key, value in kwargs.items()
   )
)
```

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬────────────────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ query          │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---            │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ list[bool]     │
╞═════╪═════╪════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ [false, false] │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ [true, true]   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ [false, false] │
│ 2   ┆ 7   ┆ [true, false]  │
│ 1   ┆ 8   ┆ [false, false] │
└─────┴─────┴────────────────┘
```

If you wanted to filter rows based on this, you can use
[`.all_horizontal()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.all_horizontal.html#polars.all_horizontal) to *AND* the booleans:
<sup>([`.any_horizontal()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.any_horizontal.html) for *OR*)</sup>

```py
df.filter(
   pl.all_horizontal(
      pl.col(key) == pl.lit(value) for key, value in kwargs.items()
   )
)
```

```
shape: (1, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 2   ┆ 5   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

- [`pl.sql_expr` / `SQLContext`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.sql_expr.html) may also be of interest: [Pandas.eval replacement in polars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76762540/pandas-eval-replacement-in-polars/76762637)